# How to Programatically Replace Files's Permissions with Father's?

Tags: windows, permissions, .net-1.1

I have a folder with permissions already set, in that folder I have some files that should all have the same permissions as the parent folder, the only thing is when these files get replaced by the updater the permissions change.

How can I have the updater replace these files's permissions again with the parent folder's?

Answer (score 0):

Deal with acls sometimes could be annoying, be careful and good luck.

Here is a well-explained article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163885.aspx
And you could see the icacls and cacls commandline tools.

Use with careful and try to backup before.

Comment: AFAIK the method `GetAccessControl()` on files and directories is only available from .NET 2.0 on. My question is for .NET 1.1.